# VichUploaderBundle Symfony3 imageFile returns null

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

Uploading an image via form works like intended. imageName, imageSize and updatedAt fields change in database as they should. However when trying to get that uploaded image to render in a twig template it returns imageFile as null

QuestionType form class:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('question', null, array('label'=>'Klausimas'))
        ->add('answer', null, array('label'=>'Atsakymas'))
        ->add('categoryName',null, array('label'=> 'Kategorija'))
        ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, array(
            'allow_delete'=>false,
            'download_uri'=>false
        ));
    }
```

Question entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="question")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @var string
     */
    private $imageName;
    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="images", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $imageSize;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @param File|UploadedFile $imageName
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $imageName = null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageName;

        if (null !== $imageName){
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setImageName(?string $imageName): void
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;
    }

    public function getImageName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    public function setImageSize(?int $imageSize): void
    {
        $this->imageSize = $imageSize;
    }

    public function getImageSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->imageSize;
    }

}
```

config.yml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        images:
            uri_prefix: /images
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/images'

            delete_on_update: false
```

twig template for editing(uploading images):

```
{{ form_start(edit_form) }}
    {{ form_widget(edit_form, {'multipart': 'true'} ) }}
    <input style="margin-top: 10px" type="submit" value="Išsaugoti" class="btn btn-success" />
{{ form_end(edit_form) }}
```

twig template that should display it:

```
    <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(question, 'imageFile', 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Question') }}"/>
```

My first guess is that I added multipart for my form in the wrong place (or using incorrect syntax), but I can't find (or don't get it) the correct way to set that

Firefox says: could not load the image when I mouse over the  tag in dev tools

Chrome says:

> GET http://helper/images/index%20-%20Copy.jpg 404 (Not Found)

**EDIT**

I've found out that `{{ form_start(edit_form}}` sets form to multipart already so there's no need to pass the option here `{{ form_widget(edit_form, {'multipart': 'true'} ) }}`. Just gonna leave it above incase anyone else tries it as a solution